# Ejecución de comando SSH desde Java manda status code 255, pero en la terminal si funciona

Tags: java, ssh

Estoy intentado desarrollar una pequeña aplicación que me permita enviar determinados comandos por SSH a un servidor remoto. Si lo intento desde la terminal de Linux o desde el Command Prompt de Windows funciona sin problemas, pero cuando lo hago desde mi aplicación Java siempre me responde con un código de estado 255.

He desactivado el firewall y he cambiado el puerto por donde tengo escuchando SSH en el servidor a 22, porque uso otro, pero nada funciona. No me lanza excepciones ni nada y si se conecta sin problemas. ¿Alguna idea?

He probado con las bibliotecas [sshj](https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj) y [jsch](/questions/tagged/jsch) y con ambas tengo el mismo problema.

**Ejemplo con sshj**

```
private void sshj() throws Exception {
    SSHClient ssh = new SSHClient();
    ssh.addHostKeyVerifier((s, i, publicKey) -> true);
    ssh.connect("servidor", 22);
    Session session = null;
    try {
        ssh.authPassword("usuario", "conrtaseña");
        session = ssh.startSession();
        Session.Command cmd = session.exec("un comando cualquiera");
        System.out.println(IOUtils.readFully(cmd.getInputStream()).toString());
        cmd.join(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println("Exit status: " + cmd.getExitStatus());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (session != null) {
            session.close();
        }

        ssh.disconnect();
    }
}
```

**Ejemplo con JSch**

```
private static void jsch() throws Exception {
    JSch js = new JSch();
    Session s = js.getSession("usuario", "servidor", 22);
    s.setPassword("contraseña");
    Properties config = new Properties();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    s.setConfig(config);
    s.connect();

    Channel c = s.openChannel("exec");
    ChannelExec ce = (ChannelExec) c;
    ce.setCommand("un comando cualquiera");
    ce.connect();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ce.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }

    ce.disconnect();
    s.disconnect();

    System.out.println("Exit status: " + ce.getExitStatus());
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885748/ssh-script-returns-255-error

Comment: @abrahamhs, ya probé y verifiqué todo eso. Incluso he agregado a la configuración las entradoas `ForwardAgent no` y ´IdentityAgent none´, pero sigo teniendo el mismo problema.